# UITableView Lines Missing When Drawing in ImageView

Tags: uitableview, ios7

Can someone tell me why my row separate lines for a UITableView (displayed in a popover) disappear when I draw in the cell.imageView?

I have the following code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(24, 24);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(itemSize);
CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
colorWithNameKey:colorLabel.colorNameKey];

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(contextRef, 255.0f, 90.0f, 90.0f, 1.0f);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(contextRef, CGRectMake(4.0, 4.0, 18.0, 18.0));
cell.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

It draws a small white circle in the optional imageView of UITableViewCellStyleDefault. Looks fine in the simulator, but on my device the gray row separator lines are missing. I have tried reducing the size of the circle, but it did not have an impact.

As a test, I tried replacing the drawn circle with a small image. No lines there either.

I do not see any reference to a style difference in the [UITableViewCell Class reference for imageView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938-CH3-SW45) or [UITableViewStyleDefault](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938-CH3-SW47).

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Is is possible that the image you're rendering into is non-retina, while your device's screen is? The line on retina devices are only 0.5pt.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue. It seems to me that only the cell.contentView has a border. I ended up with my own imageView as a subView of the contentView.

Answer (score 0):

The solution turns out to do with the Xib file. I needed to update the Interface Builder Document option from Opens in: XCode 4.6 to Default (6.0).[image]

That updated the Xib display in Interface Builder to look like modern iOS, instead of old iOS Grouped Table with vertical lines.